# subjects in different periods during a session in ztree?

Tags: ztree

I have an individual decision making program coded up on ztree. The problem is that it does not allow one zleaf to move on to the next period if another zleaf is still on the current period. Given the design of my experiment, I cannot have a subject wait to move on to the next period until others have made their decision. Is there a way to allow multiple subjects to be in different periods during a session?

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow the participants to move on individually in a session you can change the settings of every Stage to "Start if possible".

[image: Here you can find a screen shot.]